# Is there an extension or module that authenticates a domain name as a group?

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, customer

I need a module or extension that will authenticate a domain, perhaps by a group I provide in the admin panel.

**Example**:
I want ONLY users with @apple.com to be allowed to register with my Magento site.  They will enter in their email address, a script will verify that it is @apple.com and it will allow that user to register, with an email that will verify their account is ready.

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE! Don't be too put off, but asking [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are frowned upon.

Comment: Hm? this is a Development question

Comment: @teamsonassi I'm pretty sure this was directly addressed during the Area51 proposal stage, and module recommendations are specifically allowed.  Third party modules are such a key part of the Magento ecosystem and a StackExchange site would be worse without them.

Comment: @AlanStorm I'm just going off [this]( http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73/questions-about-extensions) - where it states overly vague, non-researched questions are not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a very simple extension with an observer hooking into `customer_save_before` doing any of the validation you require.

You'd probably want to have some JS validation before that though - otherwise, you'll have quite a few annoyed people who have typed in all their details on registration only to be penalised for not being an <strike>Apple fanboy</strike> apple.com email user.

Comment: and throw an exception if the validation fails. the message will show up on the frontend

Comment: I like your example, and your second point--I planning to have multiple stores and I only want validation for that store view. Could this be done that way?

Comment: Sure, just put a conditional statement in for the store view.